# Best way to execute a statement in every if-else case

Tags: c, if-statement

I often find myself repeating some code at the end of all branches of an if-else chain:

Example:

```c
if (cond1) {
    // [...] code 1

    // repeated code
} else if (cond2) {
    // [...] code 2

    // repeated code
} else if (cond3) {
    // [...] code 3

    // repeated code
}
```

What is the best way to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) here ?

I thought of the following:

- Put the repeated code in a function: you still need to repeat the call to the function in each branch.
- Have a new if condition after the if-else chain (big "or" of all previous conditions): you need to repeat the previous conditions.
- Why doesn't something exist for this? I wish a keyword, a bit like `finally` for exceptions, was possible to use after if-else chain. It would execute code only if one of the earlier condition turned out to be true:

```c
if (cond1) {
    // [...] code 1
} else if (cond2) {
    // [...] code 2
} else if (cond3) {
    // [...] code 3
} wrapup {
    // repeated code
}
```

How do you solve this problem in your code ?

**Note**: this question is tagged for the `C` language, but I am interested to also see solutions from other programming languages that might have a nice construct for that kind of program flow/path.

Comment: Is there an else clause that covers the rest of the cases or are there some conditions not covered by your else/if chain?

Comment: "DRY" quite often does more harm than good, when people start to overthink it. However, very long if-else chains are indeed a bit hard to read. These situations need to be dealt with on case to case basis, there's no one size fits all solution. Therefore a question based on pseudo code is probably not meaningful. One solution is for example to pre-calculate all conditions and then use a jump table, but that might be terribly inefficient depending on the nature of the conditions.

Comment: As for "finally", there's `else if ... else { nothing_was_true = true; } ... if(!nothing_was_true) { wrap_up(); }`

Comment: For example, if the conditions are all `strcmp` calls then the correct solution is probably to replace the if-else with a binary search.

Comment: Depends on code 1, code 2, and ... If there are any invariant pieces of codes in them, get it out of branches. Perhaps you will be able to use ```switch-case``` in a neater way as well.

Comment: @Lundin the `nothing_was_true` is a pretty good idea

Comment: @JonathanLeffler some conditions are indeed not covered by the if-else chain.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh I don't see how the `switch-case` construct helps, feel free to post an answer demonstrating what you mean.

Comment: "I wish a keyword, a bit like finally for exceptions, was possible to use after if-else chain" Sounds like you wish C was as powerful a language from the lisp family (a language that has every syntactic feature and notation you can imagine because it lets you *extend* the language syntax to meet the needs of your application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//  Start block in which we expect to do wrap-up code except in unmatched case.
do
{
    if (Condition0)
    {
        Code0;
    }
    else if (Condition1)
    {
        Code1;
    }
    else if (Condition2)
    {
        Code2;
    }
    else
        break;

    //  Perform the wrap-up code in all cases except the above else-break.
    WrapUpCode;
} while (0);
```

Comment: No flag, no macro, nice construct !

Comment: That is certainly a **neat trick**! People reading this code may be quite puzzled why it was written in such an unintuitive way

Answer (score 6):

**Set a flag**

```
if (cond1) {
    // [...] code 1
    // repeated code
} else if (cond2) {
    // [...] code 2
    // repeated code
} else if (cond3) {
    // [...] code 3
    // repeated code
}
```

-->

```
repeat = true;
if (cond1) {
    // [...] code 1
} else if (cond2) {
    // [...] code 2
} else if (cond3) {
    // [...] code 3
} else {
  repeat = false;
}

if (repeat) {
  // repeated code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the function you could return if none of the cases is true and execute the code after the if statement:

```
if (cond1) {
    // [...] code 1
} else if (cond2) {
    // [...] code
} else if (cond3) {
    // [...] code 3
} else {
    return
}

// repeated code
```

Comment: This is not general enough. I might already use return statements in `code 1/2/3`.
On top of that, this makes an assumption on the return type of the function.
See @Lundin's comment on question for a similar, more general approach.

Comment: @gruvw: Re “I might already use return statements in `code 1/2/3`”: If you have return statements in that code before the repeated code, the program is not going to execute any “repeated code” after the return statement. If you have a return statement in or after the repeated code, then it will function fine as part of the repeated code. And there is no real assumption here about the return type of the function; you can adapt the `return` statement to whatever is suitable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what I meant here is that I need to adapt the return value of the function with this answer to include some kind of "error value" and have it checked on the caller code. This is problematic for libraries that have a fixed, predefined API already. Your proposed solution does not have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since someone already opened Pandora's Box of Fugly Macros... here's a counter example. There *is* a best practice way to use macros to reduce code repetition, namely the design pattern known as "X macros". Like any macro solution, it should be the ***last resort***, when you have a big code repetition problem. For example when trying to maintain an existing code base with bad code.

X macros very good for centralizing maintenance to one single place in the code, and they are very bad for readability and debugging.

X macros works by centralizing all modifications to one single place: an abstract list of parameters. Each parameter in the list will have a macro applied to it, doing something with those parameters on a case-by-case basis.

You'd write the list like this:

```c
#define CONDITIONS(X)                \
  X(1==2, func1)                     \
  X(0==NULL, func2)                  \
```

Then do something on every item in the list through a macro, for example:

```
#define ELSE_IF(cond,code) else if(cond) { code(); wrap_up(); }
```

And call it as:

```
CONDITIONS1(ELSE_IF)
```

This now expands to:

```
else if(1==2) { func1(); wrap_up(); } else if(0==NULL) { func2(); wrap_up(); }
```

Full example:

```c
void func1 (void);
void func2 (void);
void func3 (void);
void wrap_up (void);

#define CONDITIONS1(X) if(0){}       \
  X(1==2, func1)                     \
  X(0==NULL, func2)                  \
  X(strcmp("hello","world"), func3)  \

#define CONDITIONS2(X) if(0){}       \
  X('a'=='b', func1)                 \
  X(10 == 0xA, func2)                \

#define ELSE_IF(cond,code) else if(cond) { code(); wrap_up(); }

int main (void)
{

  CONDITIONS1(ELSE_IF)
  CONDITIONS2(ELSE_IF)
}
```

Pre-processed (`gcc -E`):

```c
if(0){} else if(1==2) { func1(); wrap_up(); } else if(0==((void *)0)) { func2(); wrap_up(); } else if(strcmp("hello","world")) { func3(); wrap_up(); }
if(0){} else if('a'=='b') { func1(); wrap_up(); } else if(10 == 0xA) { func2(); wrap_up(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If not *all* `true` branches contains the repeated code, you could assign a boolean variable for those that should trigger the repeated code to be executed:

```c
bool doit = false;

if ((doit = (cond1))) {        // Trigger the repeated code to execute if true
    // [...] code 1
} else if (cond2) {            // Don't trigger the repeated code to execute if true
    // [...] code 2 
} else if ((doit = (cond3))) { // Trigger the repeated code to execute if true
    // [...] code 3 
}

if (doit) {
    // previously repeated code
}

// the rest of the function
```

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan of this style - it doesn't exactly reduce code repetition. You might as well do `if(cond1) { ... doit = true; } else if(cond2) { ... } else if(cond3) { ... doit=true; }` More readable, same amount of repetition.

Comment: @Lundin Presumably, the code in the repeated block is more complex than assigning `true` to a variable, so in that sense, it reduces repetition and it reduces the cognitive load when looking at the code since all the repeated code is in one place and you don't have to check for minor differences in each `true` branch.  As for where to put the assignment, I find it easier to spot when browsing the code if done like I showed, but, it's a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: "Presumably, the code in the repeated block is more complex" Then it needs to be a function.

Comment: @Lundin There's certainly some kind of threshold for when it's time to make a function, when the current function stops doing one thing only (and doing it well), and it seems OP's threshold for when it's time isn't crossed in these cases - but I agree, breaking it down into smaller building blocks usually makes it easier to reassemble the pieces into clear, copy/paste-free code.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those rare times when the poor shunned goto statement just might have a use case.

```
if (cond1) {
    // [...] code 1
} else if (cond2) {
    // [...] code 2
} else if (cond3) {
    // [...] code 3
} else {
    goto AFTER_REPEATED_CODE;
}

// repeated code

AFTER_REPEATED_CODE:

[...]
```

Answer (score -3):

the main focus of C programming language is not being easy-to-write or having syntactic sugars.

but you can use macros if you don't care about your code becomes a little messy.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  #define repeated_code printf("hey");
  #define if2(cond, code) if(cond){code; repeated_code;}
  #define elif2(cond, code) else if(cond){code; repeated_code;}

  if2(0, {
    printf("first branch ");
  })
  elif2(1, {
    printf("second branch.");
  })
}
```

Comment: Inventing some alternative macro language is very bad practice. This is exactly what I meant when I said that "DRY" is often harmful. If resorting to macros to reduce code repetition, then at least use X macros which is a well-known design pattern.

Comment: Dear @Lundin, It is not a bad practice when you know what  you are doing, the question that I answered actually needs some magic using macros. I code in Nim and LISP and using macros/templates is not considered "bad" at all. I don't know what is the problem with those who gave -1 to my answer.

Comment: I disagree, re-inventing the C language syntax by means of function-like macros is always bad practice and there is broad consensus among C programmers agreeing there. Writing this kind of code in a professional context will get you fired, period. Simply read any coding standard for C and you'll find rules against abusing function-like macros. Now as it happens, there are design patterns for how you can write function-like macros in a somewhat organized and readable way. I posted an answer demonstrating how.

Comment: You don't solve the repetition problem by trying to hide it. The repeated code is still there!

Comment: @BoP that's the point! but it looks better when you have more `else if` branches

Comment: @Lundin my macro looks a lot more readable than yours

Comment: @hamidb80 X macros are quite evil to read indeed, when you aren't used to that design pattern. They are somewhat common knowledge however, as opposed to inventing some new "secret macro language" which is known by 1 person in the world. That is, until 5 years from now when someone, quite likely yourself, is maintaining the code. At that point the secret macro language is known by exactly 0 people and you have to re-learn it, accompanied with the mandatory cursing. It ends up with a very high wtf/min ratio.

Comment: _"I code in Nim and LISP...."_ -- Lisp (not LISP) macros are an entirely different thing, and even in Lisp the conventional wisdom is that you write macros when you have to, but not when other reasonable solutions exist. _"...the question that I answered actually needs some magic using macros."_ -- This problem is [easily solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756498/best-way-to-execute-a-statement-in-every-if-else-case#comment137081975_77756498) without macros, so introducing some hacky one-off macro syntax is certainly a bad idea.

Comment: @adabsurdum seriously? Cuz `cond` in clojure comverts to nested `if` & `else`s

Comment: @hamidb80 -- C is none of Lisp, Clojure, Nim, etc., and C macros are an entirely different beast. But as for _"seriously"_, yes. Of course all three of Common Lisp, Clojure, and Nim use macros to implement the language. This does not mean that users should write lots of macros when other constructs will work at least as well.

Comment: @adabsurdum yes I do agree with you brother, I got the point, thanks